# Get product attribute value in magento REST API XML

Tags: rest, magento

I want to get the product's attribute value in Magento 1.9 REST API XML, currently it shows the ID.
Where to start?

```
<magento_api>
  <entity_id>875</entity_id>
  <type_id>configurable</type_id>
  <sku>shw005</sku>
  <name>Ellis Flat</name>
  <meta_title/>
  <meta_description/>
  <color>24</color>         <== I need the value, for example "blue"
  <occasion>31</occasion>   <== I need the value
  <shoe_size/>
  <gendered>207</gendered>  <== I need the value
  ...
```

Comment: Please don't show it as an image - put the actual XML as text - then show your code and what you expect to see.